# How to calculate width of list items

Tags: jquery

Im trying to calculate with of different list items

my HTML:

```
  <ul>

     <li style="disply:block; float:left">Some Text</li>
     <li style="disply:block; float:left">Some More Text</li>
     <li style="disply:block; float:left">Some Other Text</li>

 </ul>
```

Im usind standard with function

`var width = $('li').outerWidth()`

But this calculates the same width for every tag based on first one.

How can I get different widths? What As i final result I would like to have div after li with li width before... if this makes sens?

```
  <ul>

     <li style="disply:block; float:left">Some Text</li>
       <div style="width" />
     <li style="disply:block; float:left">Some More Text</li>
       <div style="width" />
     <li style="disply:block; float:left">Some Other Text</li>
       <div style="width" />

 </ul>
```

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: disply should be display. Not sure if this is a typo in your coding or when you were posting this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$('li').outerWidth()` will get the width of the first `<li>`, as you have found out.

[From the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerWidth)

> Get the outer width (includes the
>   border and padding by default) for the
>   first matched element.

What we need is the widths of each, so something like [`$.map()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map) will work nicely. This'll give us an array of widths

```
var widths = $.map($('li'), function(e) {
    return $(e).outerwidth();
});
```

**EDIT:**

How about this

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var width = $this.outerWidth();
    $this.after($('<div style="width:' + width + 'px" >'));
});
```